# Android Device Monitor won't start

Tags: android

When I try to run Android Device Monitor, it fails to start, and creates the log included below. I'd be grateful for any ideas about how I might fix this.

```
!SESSION 2016-01-29 14:55:29.262 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_25
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/xxxxx/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -data @noDefault -keyring /Users/xxxxx/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-01-29 14:55:29.799
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-01-29 14:55:29.802
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.jasper.glassfish_2.2.2.v201205150955.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-01-29 14:55:29.803
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.lucene.core_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-01-29 14:55:29.836
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.base_3.6.101.v201302041200.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-01-29 14:55:29.836
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.ui_3.5.201.v20130108-092756.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-01-29 14:55:29.836
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.webapp_3.6.101.v20130116-182509.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-01-29 14:55:29.838
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.jetty.server_8.1.3.v20120522.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-01-29 14:55:29.842
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.platform.doc.user_4.2.2.v20130121-200410.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-01-29 14:55:29.843
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.team.core_3.6.100.v20120524-0627.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-01-29 14:55:29.844
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.team.ui_3.6.201.v20130125-135424.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-01-29 14:55:29.845
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-01-29 14:55:29.848
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.ui.intro_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.192
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.192
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.193
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.193
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.193
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.apache.lucene_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.193
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.193
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.apache.lucene.analysis_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene.analysis 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.193
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.193
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper_1.0.400.v20120912-130548.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.193
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.193
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.apache.jasper.servlet_[0.0.0,6.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.193
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal_3.2.600.v20120912-155524/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.193
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.193
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry_1.0.300.v20120912-130548.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.193
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.193
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jetty.security_8.1.3.v20120522.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.193
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.193
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.193
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_3.7.0.v20120523-1543.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.193
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.core_[3.4.100,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.193
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.ui_[3.4.100,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.193
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_8.1.3.v20120522.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.193
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.193
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.session_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.193
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.193
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.193
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.193
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.0.1.v20121109-203239.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.193
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.194
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.194
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.194
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.194
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.session_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.194
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.255
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.255
!MESSAGE Bundle org.apache.lucene_2.9.1.v201101211721 [25] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.analysis_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.highlighter_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.memory_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.queries_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.snowball_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.spellchecker_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.misc_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Bundle org.apache.lucene.analysis_2.9.1.v201101211721 [26] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene.analysis 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.0.1.v20121109-203239 [89] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.session_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper_1.0.400.v20120912-130548 [92] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.apache.jasper.servlet_[0.0.0,6.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry_1.0.300.v20120912-130548 [93] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jetty.security_8.1.3.v20120522 [136] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_8.1.3.v20120522 [137] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package org.eclipse.jetty.jmx_8.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.security_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.256
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.257
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.257
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.session_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.257
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.257
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_3.7.0.v20120523-1543 [145] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.257
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.core_[3.4.100,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.257
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.ui_[3.4.100,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.257
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200 [148] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.257
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.257
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.257
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.257
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.search_3.8.0.v20120523-1540 [150] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.search 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.257
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.257
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal_3.2.600.v20120912-155524 [162] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.257
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.257
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources_3.4.400.v20120705-114010 [164] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources 2 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.257
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_[3.5.0,4.0.0).

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-01-29 14:55:31.259
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.URIUtil.toURI(URIUtil.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ResourceHandler.loadMostRecentModel(ResourceHandler.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.loadApplicationModel(E4Application.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.MonitorApplication.start(MonitorApplication.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72610) was helpful.  I couldn't determine which process the device monitor was, so I just restarted my machine.  That fixed the problem.